# Calculating $\int_{\Bbb R^3}\langle x,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle x,w \rangle^{16}\;e^{-|x|}\;dx_1dx_2dx_3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Let $v,w\in \Bbb R^3$ two orthogonal vectors of length $1$. Calculate: 
$$\int_{\Bbb R^3}\langle x,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle x,w \rangle^{16}\;e^{-|x|}\;dx_1dx_2dx_3$$

---

My attempt: Using the coarea formula:
$$\int_{\Bbb R^3}\langle x,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle x,w \rangle^{16}\;e^{-|x|}\;dx_1dx_2dx_3=\lim_{r \to \infty }\int_{B_r}\langle x,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle x,w \rangle^{16}\;e^{-|x|}\;dx_1dx_2dx_3 $$
$$=\lim_{r \to \infty}\int_0^r\int_{\rho S^2}\langle x,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle x,w \rangle^{16}\;e^{-|x|}dS(x)d\rho$$$$=\lim_{r \to \infty}\int_0^r\rho ^2\int_{ S^2}\langle \rho y,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle \rho y,w \rangle^{16}\;e^{-|\rho y|}dS(y)d\rho=\biggr(\lim_{r \to \infty}\int_0^r\rho ^{38}e^{-\rho}d\rho\biggr)\biggr(\int_{ S^2}\langle y,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle y,w \rangle^{16}dS(y)\biggr)=\Gamma(39)\int_{ S^2}\langle y,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle y,w \rangle^{16}dS$$

Now I need to calculate $\int_{ S^2}\langle y,v \rangle^{20} \;\langle y,w \rangle^{16}dS$, which is the part I'm having trouble with. Since $v,w$ are orthogonal vectors of length $1$, I can assume without loss of generality (since the surface integral over a sphere doesn't change under orthogonal transformation) that $v=(0,0,1), w=(0,1,0)$. Then I'm left with   $\int_{ S^2}y_3^{20}y_2^{16}dS$, which I'm pretty stuck with. Using the parametrization $(\varphi, \theta) \mapsto (\cos\theta \sin \varphi,\sin \theta \sin \varphi, \cos \varphi)$, $0\leq \varphi \leq \pi$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, we get: 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos ^{20}\varphi \sin^{17}\varphi \sin^{16} \theta d\varphi d\theta$$

Any ideas how to continue from here?

Comment: $\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos ^2\varphi \sin^{17}\varphi \sin^{16} \theta d\varphi d\theta=\left(\int_0^{\pi}\cos ^2\varphi \sin^{17}\varphi d\varphi \right)\left(\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{16} \theta d\theta\right)$

Comment: How can I calculate those integrals?

Comment: Methods for these integrals should be in any calculus textbook.  First one easy substitution.  Both by reduction formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pedestrian answer, i am just continuing the calculus of the two (extracted) integrals from the last lines of the OP.

(1)

First of all, recall the relation for the Beta-Function $B$, that is relevant for us:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
=B(x,y)
=2\int_0^{\pi/2}
\sin^{2x-1} t\;
\cos^{2y-1} t\;
d t\ .
\\[3mm]
&\text{This gives immediately}
\\
&\int_0^\pi
\cos^{20}s\; \sin^{17} s\; ds 
=
2
\int_0^{\pi/2}
\cos^{20}s\; \sin^{17} s\; ds 
\\
&\qquad=
B\left(\frac{20+1}2,\; \frac{17+1}2\right)
=
\frac
{
\Gamma\left(\frac{21}2\right)
\Gamma(9)
}
{
\Gamma\left(\frac{39}2\right)
}
\\
&
\qquad
=
\frac
{
\Gamma\left(\frac{21}2\right)
\cdot 8!}
{
\frac{37}2\cdot
\frac{35}2\cdot
\frac{33}2\cdot
\frac{31}2\cdot
\frac{29}2\cdot
\frac{27}2\cdot
\frac{25}2\cdot
\frac{23}2\cdot
\frac{21}2\cdot
\Gamma\left(\frac{21}2\right)
}
\\
&\qquad=
\frac{8!\cdot 2^9}
{
37\cdot
35\cdot
33\cdot
31\cdot
29\cdot
27\cdot
25\cdot
23\cdot
21}\ .
\\[3mm]
&\text{In the same spirit}
\\
&\int_0^{2\pi}
\sin^{16} t\; dt
=
2B\left(\frac{16+1}2,\; \frac{0+1}2\right)
=
2\cdot 
\frac
{
\Gamma\left(\frac{17}2\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}2\right)
}
{
\Gamma(9)
}
\\
&
\qquad
=
2\cdot
\frac
{
\frac{15}2\cdot
\frac{13}2\cdot
\frac{11}2\cdot
\frac{9}2\cdot
\frac{7}2\cdot
\frac{5}2\cdot
\frac{3}2\cdot
\frac{1}2\cdot
\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)^2
}
{
8!}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

(2)

Following the OP and the above computational path we have for the initial integral 
$$
J = 
\iiint_{\Bbb R^3}x_1^{20}\;x_2^{16}\; e^{-\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}}\; dx_1\; dx_2\; dx_3
$$
by using a passage to spherical coordinates, 
$(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ to $(r,s,t)$, with 
$x_1=r\sin s\cos t$, 
$x_2=r\sin s\sin t$, 
$x_3=r\cos s$,
$dx_1\; dx_2\; dx_3=r^{\color{red}2}\; \sin s\; dr\, ds\, dt$ 
the formula
$$
\begin{aligned}
J
&=
2\cdot
\Gamma(\color{red}{39})
\cdot
\frac{\Gamma(21/2)\;\Gamma(9)}{\Gamma(37/2)}
\cdot
\frac{\Gamma(17/2)\;\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(9)}
\\
&=
2\cdot\frac{\Gamma(39)}{\Gamma(39/2)}
\cdot
\Gamma\left(\frac{20+1}2\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{16+1}2\right)
\Gamma\left(\frac{ 0+1}2\right)
\\
&=2\cdot 2^{19}\; 38!!\cdot 19!!\cdot 15!!\cdot \pi
\\
&=2\cdot 2^{19}\cdot 2^{19}\cdot 19!!\cdot 19!!\cdot 15!!\cdot \pi
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
But we could also go the following way, first use a change of variables
$x=r\cos t$, $y=r\sin t$, $z=z$, thus
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=
\int_{r\in[0,\infty)}
\int_{t\in[0,2\pi]}
r^{20+16}\; \cos^{20} t\; \sin^{16}t\; r\; dr\; dt
\int_{z\in\Bbb R}
e^{-\sqrt{r^2+t^2}}
\; dz
\\
&=
2B(21/2, 17/2)
\int_{r\in[0,\infty)}
\int_{z\in\Bbb R}
r^{37}\; 
e^{-\sqrt{r^2+t^2}}
\; dz
\; dr
\qquad\text{ now }r=R\cos s\dots
\\
&=
2B(21/2, 17/2)
\int_{R\in[0,\infty)}
\int_{s\in[0,\pi]}
R^{37}\; \cos s^{37} 
\; 
e^{-R}
\; R\; dR\; ds
\\
&= 2B(21/2, 17/2)\cdot B(19,1/2)\cdot \Gamma(39)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We introduce instead of the beta functions the gamma functions,
obtain the same result.

Or we could have taken instead of $x_1^{20}x_2^{16}$ any other of the "same shape",
$x_j^{20}x_k^{16}$, with $1\le j,k\le 3$, $j\ne k$,
then perform the same substitutions, transform to obtain beta functions and gamma functions, then finally only gamma functions. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

Integration of polynomials over a unit sphere is a well-known topic; [this post](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2018/01/31/integrating-polynomials-over-a-sphere-or-ball/) gives, for your case,

$$\int y_2^{16}y_3^{20}dS = 2\frac{\Gamma\left({1\over 2}\right)\Gamma\left({17\over 2}\right)\Gamma\left({21\over 2}\right)}{\Gamma\left({39\over 2}\right)}$$

The post contains references for the corresponding proofs.